# 500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection, on bluemix when connecting to Exchange web services

Tags: ibm-cloud, exchangewebservices, websphere-liberty

I have a Liberty Websphere application hosted on Bluemix that connects to Exchange Web Services. When I run this api on localhost it works fine and returns the desired results. But when I host it on bluemix, it returns the error
***"500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection"***

No errors in the logs.

i have tried the solutions given in other posts and searched a lot on internet. But still not able to solve this issue.

Comment: Does your backend process takes longer than 2 minutes to complete? Bluemix Datapower will close the connection if it stays idle more than 2 minutes.

Comment: It takes about 30 seconds. On bluemix, I changed the http timeout period to 5 minutes and then tried it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: ok - changing the timeout would not help here. Could you please add the output of  `cf logs <app-name> --recent` to your question? Please do not add as comment since it would be difficult to read.

Comment: there are no errors or any other information in the logs. This error is returned when I consume the API through Postman.

Comment: Could you please let me know how did you deploy your app?

Comment: I export it as a WAR file and then deploy it using cf push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem is resolved. There was a configuration error in the application as my company's Bluemix server is on dev environment and the application was trying to connect to the prod environment.

When we connected using the dev IDs, from dev bluemix servers to dev exchange servers, the application works fine.